# Javascript Image Slideshow issue

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new in web development field.

I'm creating a web page. In home page there are a javascript image Slideshow Please check it here: http://bluearrowsystems.com/index.php. Now the slider images are auto moving. But is there any way to move the images when I place my mouse on the image thats mean mouseover ?

Following is my html head section javascript code, I think but not sure, in this section it's need to add a javascript code.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="res/responsiveslides.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="res/example.css">
<script src="res/ga.js"></script>
<script src="res/jquery.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="http://viljamis.com/js/libs/jquery-
1.8.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
<script src="res/responsiveslides.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {

  // Slideshow 1
  $(".rslides1").responsiveSlides({
    speed: 1000,
    maxwidth: 1024,                                     
    auto:false,



  });


      // Slideshow 2
  $(".rslides2").responsiveSlides({
    auto: true,
    pager: true,
    speed: 500,
    maxwidth: 540,

  });

});
</script>
```

Comment: anyone answer my question plz

Answer (score 0):

The plugin you are using does not have a method to trigger playback externally.
Your could use an other plugin like flexslider.
With it you would get the functionality you need like so:

```
$('.rslides1').flexslider().on('mouseover', function(){
    $(this).data('flexslider').next();
});
```

EDIT: If you want to initialize flexslider in a paused state and start playback on mouseover, use following code:

```
$('.rslides1').flexslider( {slideshow: false} ).on('mouseover', function(){
    $(this).data('flexslider').play();
});
```

Comment: can you give me an example ?

Comment: For what exactly? You just need to initialize flexslider with $('.rslides1').flexslider() and afterwards bind the mouseover event on the container, to trigger next slide every time you hover over the slideshow container. Examples on how to use the plugin can be examined on the developer page http://flexslider.woothemes.com/